# Want to display to date based on duration selection and from date

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

my html form is like this.

```
 <tr>        <td>Duration</td>
     <td>
     <select name="duration"> 
       <option value="1">1month duration</option>
       <option value="2">2month duration</option>
   <option value="3">3month duration</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>from date</td>
<td><input type="text" name="fromdate"/>(i used date picker here)</td>

<td>To date</td>
<td><input type="text" name="todate"/>(i used date picker here)</td>
 </tr>
```

Now what i want is when i select duration as 1 month and from date then in to date it should display date after 30 days  and when i select in duration 2 month and from date then in to date it should display date after 60 days

Comment: Please help me  thanks a lot in advance.i am newbiee

Comment: Why `30` and `60` days and not calendar months?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a sample script to address your problem. follow this method.

sample logic

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#fromDate").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(){     
               var fromDate = $("#fromDate").datepicker('getDate');
               var days = parseInt($("#duration").val()*30);
               var toDate = new Date(fromDate.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
               $("#toDate").datepicker('setDate', toDate);                              
            }
      });

    $("#fromDate").datepicker('setDate', new Date());
    $("#toDate").datepicker();
    var days = parseInt($(this).val()*30);
    toDate = new Date(new Date().getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
            $("#toDate").datepicker('setDate', toDate);        
});

$("#duration").change(function(){
     var fromDate = $("#fromDate").datepicker('getDate');
     var days = parseInt($(this).val()*30);
     var toDate = new Date(fromDate.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
     $("#toDate").datepicker('setDate', toDate);                              
});
```

working code : http://jsfiddle.net/mjobvuwp/1/

Comment: Just a note, if fromDate is changed in the textbox, toDate still responds from the current date.

Comment: how to make this work in my localhost please guide me

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`setUTCMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCMonth) or [`setUTCDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCDate) (combined with `getUTCMonth` or `getUTCDate`, respectively) methods of [*Date*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```
var d = new Date(), // your starting Date object
    d1m,
    d30d;

// setting d1m = d + 1 month
d1m = new Date(d); // start the same as d
d1m.setUTCMonth(d1m.getUTCMonth() + 1); // add 1 month
console.log(d1m); // ready to use, so e.g. see what we've got

// setting d30d = d + 30 days
d30d = new Date(d); // start the same as d
d30d.setUTCDate(d30d.getUTCDate() + 30); // add 30 days
console.log(d30d); // ready to use, so e.g. see what we've got
```

Comment: thanks a lot  but i need it using javascript   for my html page.